# Don't run Bundler as root - Rails6 on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bundler

I've been trying to deploy a Rails 6 application to Elastic Beanstalk and have been stuck with this Bundle Root error for over a day. I've read through everything I can find but nothing has worked so far.

> [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [stage ruby application]. Stop running the command. Error: install dependencies in Gemfile failed with error Command /bin/sh -c bundle install --local failed with error Command timed out after 900 seconds. Stderr:Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
> installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
> users on this machine.

My gemfile:

```
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'

gem 'sendgrid-ruby'

gem 'faker'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'

gem 'sprockets', '~> 4.0'

gem 'devise'

gem 'bootstrap'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'figaro'

gem 'rails-controller-testing'

gem 'validates_zipcode'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]

gem 'minitest'
gem 'minitest-reporters'

end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', '>= 1.2016.7'
```

my .ebextension/fix_rails_6.config:

```
packages:
    yum:
        git: []

commands:
  02_download_nodejs:
    command: "curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -"
  03_install_nodejs:
    command: "yum -y install nodejs"

container_commands:
  19_precompile:
    command: "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
```

And my environment properties:

```
BUNDLER_DEPLOYMENT_MODE true
BUNDLE_WITHOUT   test:development
RACK_ENV production
RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION true
RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATION false
```

Comment: I don't think the "don't run bundler as root" is an actual problem. It's really just a warning. Can you download the logs through the Elastic Beanstalk console and see if you can get more information on errors? It looks like it is stuck on installing a Gem. Check the log file to see which one it is getting stuck on.

Comment: There is this error but I've ignored it as I upgraded everything to 5.0.4 yesterday. Both the AWS server and my code (including Gemfile.lock) are all now 5.0.4```opt/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:312:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated puma 5.0.4, but you
r Gemfile requires puma 4.3.6. Prepending bundle exec to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)```

Comment: Ok - I'm going to dig in a bit more, it seems to be hanging on nio4r, which has some relationship with puma?

Comment: I would suggest terminating the existing server and having it spin up a new instance, or use the Immutable deployment policy for the short-term so you can deploy on a clean instance each time until you have your issues worked out.

Comment: @downtownott did you ever get it up and running? I'm experiencing the same error.

Comment: Grambo I terminated the server as recommended but ran into similar but different issues. I did this a few more times with different problems each time and ultimately gave up. Sticking with Heroku for now and planning to use Hatchbox.io when I need something more sophisticated

Comment: I am running into similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68494462/build-fails-when-deploying-rails-application-on-amazon-linux-2

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have an old, out-of-date `Gemfile.lock` on the deployed server which has incorrect versions of your Gems listed.

If this builds and runs locally, I would suggest ensuring that you distribute the `Gemfile.lock` file to your server along with the rest of the code and the `Gemfile`.

If that doesn't work, remove the `Gemfile.lock` from your deployed server and try again